# Django: multiple forms how to save this not hidden

Tags: django, django-forms

I am struggling with validating a form based on damage_type choice field.
I show only one DamageTypeForm in the template (other two are hide by js .hide() function).

Each DamageTypeForm has got some required=True fields, therefore I cannot save the selected form this way:

```
def createDamage(request):
    damage_specify_form = DamageSpecify(request.POST or None)
    damage_type_form1 = DamageTypeForm1(request.POST or None)
    damage_type_form2 = DamageTypeForm2(request.POST or None)
    damage_type_form3 = DamageTypeForm3(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        damage_type  = request.POST.get('damage_type ')

        if damage_type  == 'DamageType1':
            if damage_type_form1.is_valid():
                damage_type_form1.save()
                return reverse('damage:type1')
        elif damage_type  == 'DamageType2':
            if damage_type_form2.is_valid():
                damage_type_form2.save()
                return reverse('damage:type2')
        elif damage_type  == 'DamageType3':
            if damage_type_form3.is_valid():
                damage_type_form3.save()
                return reverse('damage:type3')
    else:
        damage_type_form1 = DamageTypeForm1()
        damage_type_form2 = DamageTypeForm2()
        damage_type_form3 = DamageTypeForm3()

    context = {
        'damage_specify_form': damage_specify_form,
        'damage_type_form1': damage_type_form1,
        'damage_type_form2': damage_type_form2,
        'damage_type_form3': damage_type_form3,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_damage.html', context)
```

How can I get damage_type in View before submitting the form in the template, to save only desired form??

Comment: Can you please shall all relevant code including models, forms, and templates?

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey, you can find it in my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72652265/django-switch-a-form-in-template-depending-on-choice-field/72657168#72657168

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches you could take based on the answer to your previous question. Where it was suggested that you have:

```
<form> 
     {% csrf_token %}

     {{damage_type_form.as_p}}

     <div id="type1">
          {{damage_form_1.as_p}}
     </div>
     <div id="type2">
          {{damage_form_2.as_p}}
     </div>
     <div id="type3">
          {{damage_form_3.as_p}}
     </div>

     <input type="submit" ...>
</form>
```

I'm not so sure why it was suggested to you that way. But the issue you highlighted is that the other forms (*the hidden ones*) do have `required` fields even though their respective forms are hidden.

So one way is to use the `novalidate` attribute on the form tag:

```
<form novalidate>
     ...
</form>
```

This `novalidate` is a form-level attribute used to turn off validation for a form, despite the attributes of the inputs it contains (i.e. will override inputs with the `required` attribute, or that would otherwise fail validation).

**NOTE**: Do not use `novalidate` if you simply want to internationalize or otherwise change the content of the default error messages. This can be done with `JavaScript`.

I personally don't think using the `novalidate` attribute is a good practice even though it might come in handy for some scenarios.

On the other hand, ***(my recommendation)***, you could use `JavaScript` or `Jquery` to set/remove the fields `required` attribute if the respective form is visible or not. For example:

```
# But let's say you do have separate forms...
<form id="form-1"> 
     ...
</form>

<form id="form-2" style="display:none">  
     ...
</form>

# javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
     # using jquery here...
     $(document).ready(function(){

          # Checking for a form's visibility
          if($("#form-2").css('display') === 'none'){
              # form-2: display is none. Therefore set its field attributes required to false
               $('#form-2 input[type="text"]').removeAttr('required');

               # or
               # $('#form-2 #field_id').removeAttr('required');
          }
          else{
               # form-2: display is not none. Therefore set its field attributes required to true
               $('#form-2 input[type="text"]').attr('required','true');

               # or
               # $('#form-2 #field_id').attr('required','true');
          }
     });
</script>
```

Please note that the above `JavaScript` can be a bit cleaner, even adding some/an `event listener` to pick up when a form's `visibility` has changed: to set/remove the `required` attributes on a specific form.

That's just a basic concept of an approach I'd use.

Comment: According to your approach (1 or 2) if I need separate <form> for each my Django form, there must be a submit button in each <form> also. So, my def createDamage(request) will only validate and save one form depending on the damage_type choice field and there is no need to use any of your solutions. Correct?